# Visual Studio: Images Quality Reduced in Crystal Report Viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report in a Windows Form application (Visual Studio 2013). I am facing issue regarding image quality. I have some images which are PNG format.

I have inserted a image in Report which looks good in Visual Studio Report Designer Viewer, but It looks blurred whenever I have tried to view it in Form Control Crystal Report Viewer.

This is original image:
[image]

This is Visual Studio Designer Preview:

[image]

This is Form Control Viewer Preview which reduced the image quality.

[image]

I have also enabled Option > Retain Original Image Color Depth.

Comment: Does "I have also checked Report Option > Retain Original Image Color Depth." mean that you enabled it?

Comment: Yes it is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly SAP / Crystal Reports focuses on text based forms and as such graphical issues such as this have not been addressed in over 5 yrs!

Things you could try... SAP say that they convert the image to a bitmap to be displayed in the viewer... try converting your image to a bitmap and see if theres any loss...

You could also try altering the colour depth, try and get it as low as possible, some mention 256 as being the upper limit before major loss in quality is actioned.

Failing that do as the user who posted the following discussion on SAP forums said they will do... bypass crystal and put it in a pdf LOL

Taken from [here](https://scn.sap.com/thread/1846084)

**1)**
David Hilton 08-Dec-2010 01:49 (in response to Anthony Clewlow)

I spoke with a few people at SAP and we think the image is converted to BMP when added to the report designer. We are curious what kind of results you see if you conver the tiff to bmp before adding to the report design? Do you see similar quality now?...subject to image compression.

**then later in the thread....**

udek Uher 26-Jun-2015 20:54 (in response to Eileen Koczan)

The functionality of Crystal Reports as concerns images has not changed. Adding this as a request into the SAP Idea Place may not be a bad idea - I checked and do not see this in there.

- Ludek
  Senior Support Engineer AGS Product Support, Global Support Center Canada

**UPDATE:** You could also try reducing it to a 16 bit image, some report that those images will display as the original in the viewer.